# How to use API Connect Test and Monitor behind a firewall

Tags: apiconnect-test-monitor

It looks like API Connect test and monitor is a cloud hosted service and the HTTP access is made from a cloud server on the public internet.

How can I use this to test an API that is deployed behind my firewall? This does not seem to be documented.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud is currently limited to public APIs unfortunately but there's a desktop client under development, v1.0 just became available.

https://github.com/ibm-apiconnect/test-and-monitor/releases